# postgresql - Get specific date value each year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple query like this:

```
select
    AVG(last),
    NOW() - interval '1 YEAR' as DATE
from
    PRICE_HIST
where
    CREATED_AT between NOW() - interval '1 YEAR' and NOW() - interval '1 YEAR - 12 HOURS'
```

which returns the average price of an asset a year ago.
I would like to expand this in postgresql like a loop, to all years in my database just changing just changing the 1 year to 2, 3, 4, etc...

Any suggestions? I am open to other approaches.

Edit: As suggested by @Belayer, this is my sample data:

```
id      created_at                      last    symbol
74      2021-10-19 19:41:53.382 -0300   280000  BTCBRL
46      2019-10-19 19:41:47.481 -0300   35000   BTCBRL
49      2018-10-19 19:41:47.519 -0300   15000   BTCBRL
1432    2022-10-19 09:47:58.038 -0300   101868  BTCBRL
1481    2022-10-19 09:48:09.559 -0300   102021  BTCBRL
1513    2022-10-19 09:48:19.686 -0300   101395  BTCBRL
1517    2022-10-19 09:48:20.706 -0300   102500  BTCBRL
1531    2022-10-19 09:48:24.559 -0300   102926  BTCBRL
```

I want to get years from the database. I don't know the years, as each symbol  have a different oldest year.

Comment: Please post sample data and the expected results of that data. Post as  formatted text - **no images** - or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). Additional your question/description is ambiguous: do you want to pass a single number for number of years prior, of get each prior year in the database. Provide this by updating the question not as a comment.  Note: `Loop` in SQL is virtually always inappropriate.

Comment: You can use the function generate_series to have a serie of dates with a one year interval... As an example : SELECT * FROM generate_series('1900-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                              '1 YEAR');

Comment: @Belayer I just added your suggestions to the question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create the query after some time.

I first generated the series as suggested by @SQLpro, then I made a join. It was a bit slow, but worked.

```
with range_values AS (
    select date_trunc('day', min(created_at)) as minval,
            date_trunc('day', max(created_at - '1 year'::interval)) as maxval
            FROM price_hist where symbol= 'BTCBRL'
),
year_ranges as (
    SELECT  generate_series(minval, maxval, '1 year'::interval) as date_start from range_values
),
end_start as (
    select date_start, date_trunc('day', date_start) + interval '1 day' - interval '1 second' as date_end
    from year_ranges
)
select avg(last) as price, es.date_start as date from price_hist ph
join end_start es on ph.created_at between es.date_start and es.date_end
where ph.symbol = 'BTC'
group by es.date_start, es.date_end
order by es.date_start desc
```